# Is there a way to increase the size of the lightning dual list box and lightning input?

Tags: salesforce1-app

I have two problems here -
First -
I am trying to increase the size of the lightning dual list box but i am not able to do so, can we increase the size of the standard lightning dual list box?

code for dual list box -

```
<lightning-dual-listbox id="selectOptions" source-label="Available"
    selected-label="Selected" options={listOptions} onchange={handleChange}
</lightning-dual-listbox>
```

Second -
Is there any way we can increase the size of standard lightning input vertically?
i am able to increase its size horizontally by using - slds-col slds-size_1-of-4 but not able to increase it vertically

code for lightning input -

Answer (score 1):

In `lightning-dual-list-box` there is a `size` attribute that indicates the number of items that display in the listboxes before vertical scrollbars are displayed. Not sure if that's what you need.

Regarding `lightning-input`, it is a component which horizontal width grows to fill the space in its container. However, you cannot change its height. If you want to place it in a bigger container maybe you can play with vertical margin.

In general, you cannot apply CSS to base components internals has they are part of its [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM), unless that there is a property that allows you to manipulate it (as the lightning-dual-list-box `size` property)